# Trouble centering tcl/tk program when using grid

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

The reason I'm doing this is because I'm trying to set the window in the centre of the screen. I'm using grid not pack and I have read about using `wm grid` but don't understand how to set it. I also don't understand why `. cget -width` is returning `0` I thought grid was supposed to set the size when not given an option?

```
set width [. cget -width]
set height [. cget -height]
puts $height
puts $width
set x [expr { ( [winfo vrootwidth  .] - $width  ) / 2 }]
set y [expr { ( [winfo vrootheight .] - $height ) / 2 }]


wm title . "a3q2" 
wm geometry . ${width}x${height}+${x}+${y}
```

What am I doing wrong this time? P.S homework I don't just want a code post. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[. cget -width]` and `[. cget -height]` return the *explicitly configured* width/height of the window.  For most widgets in Tk you don't explicitly configure the dimensions.  Instead, the widgets have a "natural" width/height based on the contents of the widget.  A label, for example, is just wide/tall enough to accommodate the text in it.  A toplevel window is just big enough to fit all the widgets inside of it.

To get the actual dimensions of the window, you should use `[winfo width .]` and `[winfo height .]`.  Make sure you do that *after* the window and all of the widgets inside it have been mapped (usually that means doing an `[update]` call before the `[winfo ...]` calls).  Otherwise the geometry manager may not have updated the dimensions of the widgets/window yet.

Answer (score 0):

A note about Eric's answer: [update] is [<strike>usually</strike> almost always a mistake](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1255).  See the Tcl wiki for examples on how to avoid it.  One trick is to bind to the <configure> event and invoke [winfo ...] in the bound script.